# EPS image being cropped

Tags: r, postscript

I'm trying to save an R plot as an .eps and I want the image to have dimensions 13x340. I'm doing so like this:

```
postscript("dotplot.eps", horizontal = FALSE, onefile = FALSE, paper = "special", height = 13, width = 340)
print(pl)
dev.off()
```

pl is my plot. However, the final .eps I get is cropped so that I can only see about the middle 2/3 of the plot. The part that I can see is scaled to the size I want, but the edges are cropped off the final image. Regardless of what I set the width to in the postscript function this always happens. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: can you post a reproducible example showing the problem?

Comment: What are you using to view the EPS file with that demonstrates the cropping ?

Comment: Thank you KenS. I feel a bit stupid. It was an issue with Preview (MacOS). I opened the image in Illustrator and it is all there. I wonder why Preview is cropping it?

Comment: height / width units are inches http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grDevices/html/postscript.html. Is that really what you want?

Comment: I can't really say why Apple Preview is cropping the EPS, though seeing the EPS file might help....

Comment: likely the %%BoundingBox is incorrect and the one app is clipping to the box while the other ignores it.  You could open in a text editor and change the %%BB numbers to test if  that's what's going on.

Comment: Yes, the bounding box is incorrect and I can play around with it to fix the issue in preview. Thanks. But George makes another good point. I have a lot of data to plot, but I don't want the image to be 340inches wide. I think I just need to reduce the number of pixels per inch with "pointsize".

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar case, but I'm only missing about 1/10 of my plot at the right-hand end and I think it's just an artefact of the preview I'm using (through Dropbox on a web-browser). However, I don't know for sure as I haven't checked the .eps file in gimp or another viewer.

The problem goes away if I change the plot orientation to vertical, but that's not what we want.